# How can I use the same function for keydown and click events?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm trying to listen for two event types (`keydown` and `click`) and execute the same function (toggling the playing and pausing of some audio files) on both of them.

The event listener for `keydown` works fine but when I try to use the same function for `click`, nothing happens. Console logging `audio` is null when using `click` as event type.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Please note that I'm trying to do this in vanilla JS only (my code is based on the first project of Wes Bos' Javascript 30 course).

Here's the code:

```
  function toggleSound(e) {
    const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`); 
    const key = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
    if(!audio) return; 
    if (audio.paused) {
     audio.currentTime = 0; 
     audio.play();
     key.classList.add('playing'); 
      } else {
        audio.pause();
        key.classList.remove('playing');
      }
  };
  function removeTransition(e) {
    if(event.propertyName !== 'transform') return; 
    this.classList.remove('playing'); 
  }
  const keys = document.querySelectorAll('.key');
  keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('ended', removeTransition));

  window.addEventListener('keydown',  toggleSound);
  window.addEventListener('click', toggleSound);
```

Comment: You bind a click on a click? sounds like a bad idea. So you click an element and than you have to click again since you just bound it. Clicking that thing will bind another click event..... So now the key has 2 click handlers. Click it again, you have 3 event handlers attached.... repeat..

Comment: That makes sense to me now, thanks. The problem I'm having is that nothing happens unless `window` is the event target for the listener, yet at the same time I seem to have to loop over the keys (which are html elements). This is why I end up with having to click handlers.

Answer (score 0):

you are actually adding this listener in a wrong way,
when you use the following code:

window.addEventListener('click', clickSound)

You are running the clickSound method, and inside this method you are adding another listeners for each item in the keys array (which i don't know what is it, but i assume that it's an html element, since you are using addEventListener on it too)

to solve it you can remove this window.addEventListener('click', clickSound) and add the listeners for the keys itself

something like

```
keys.forEach(key => {
  key.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const dataKey = e.target.dataset.key;
    const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${dataKey}"]`);

    if (!audio) return; // Just to be sure the element was found
    if (audio.paused) {
      audio.currentTime = 0;
      audio.play();
      key.classList.add('playing');
    } else {
      audio.pause();
      key.classList.remove('playing');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I've tried this but audio is now null. I did manage to access the audio with no problems in the keydown function - I've edited the code in my question so it now includes it.

Comment: I've just edited my question and code to make it more concise.